# reusing of cell in table view causing button problems

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios8

I have a button on my table view cell. I am returning `numberOfRowsInSection`as `return arrayname.count`. therefore i get the same number of buttons as the array count.

I trigger a notification using that button, when the user presses that button again the notification gets canceled. It is a location based notification.

It works fine if if there is only one button in the table view. But when I return 2 or more cells, I can't seem to figure out how to distinguish between the button events without one affecting the other.
Example - there are two cells in the table and two buttons. One for location 'a' and one for location 'b'. I want a notification when i enter region 'a' so i press the button corresponding to location 'a'. but because button 'b' is not pressed the notification doesn't get scheduled. it works fine only if all the buttons are in the same state. 
but,how can i solve this problem ?

```
`button.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) 
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "a.png")!, forState: .Normal)
 button.tag = 999 
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) { 
if sender.tag == 999 
{ sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "b.png")!, forState: .Normal) 
sender.tag = 0 } else
 { sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "a.png")!, forState: .Normal) sender.tag = 999 } 
}`
```

I am already using this code to switch images on button press.

Comment: you can provide the tag with indexpath.row value and on buttonclick get the tag and work according to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   /*Buy settings the tag to your button you can identify which button is selected */
    //create a button globally  in your view controller
   uibutton*menu
   // add the below code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method
   [menus addTarget:self action:@selector(menuclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   menus.tag=indexPath.row+1;
   //identify button using button sender
  (void)menuclick:(id)sender
  {
     NSInteger tagid=[sender tag];
      if(checkbutton.isSelected)
    {
    //you can identify which button get selected
    switch (tagid)
    {
        case 1:
            //button 1 is selected
            break;
        case2:
            //button 2 is selected
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [menu setSelected:NO];
  }
  else
  {
     //you can identify which button get unselected
    switch (tagid)
    {
        case 1:
            //button 1 is selected
            break;
        case2:
            //button 2 is selected
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [menu setSelected:YES];

    }


  }
```

Comment: By setting tag to your button you can identify which button cilcked in button click event.

Comment: `button.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) button.setImage(UIImage(named: "a.png")!, forState: .Normal) button.tag = 999 func pressed(sender: UIButton!) { if sender.tag == 999 { sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "b.png")!, forState: .Normal) sender.tag = 0 } else { sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "a.png")!, forState: .Normal) sender.tag = 999 } } ` i am already using this code to switch images on button press. i m confused, how do i implement your solution ?

Comment: Tag should start from the 1 not from 0.if use zero it will get crash and set different tag value  each button .

Comment: ok. i got the index value of the button. But, the user presses the same button to schedule as well as cancel the notififcation.  so when i try to schedule a notification by pressing a button, it doesnt get scheduled because the state of the other button is the state for cancel notification.  it woks properly only when all the buttons are in the same state. how do i fix this ?

Comment: By identifying the button state  whether  the button get selected or not. if the button is unselected we can send notification  and if the button get selected when cancel the notification.

Comment: the problem with your solution is that, i dont have just two buttons. In my case number of buttons = size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

I see no connection between the problem that you have and cell reusing.

The easiest way to detect which button is pressed is to add line:

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. Then in the function which is triggered by your buttons add:

```
func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
    let selectedItem = arrayname[sender.tag] // this gives you selected item from array
    // or you can do
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        // button in first cell pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: `button.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "a.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button.tag = 999

func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
     if sender.tag == 999 {
          sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "b.png")!, forState: .Normal)
          sender.tag = 0
     } else {
          sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "a.png")!, forState: .Normal)
          sender.tag = 999
     }
}` i am already using this code to switch images on button press. i m confused, how do i implement your solution ?

Comment: @sumesh subclass your UIButton and add Boolean property which will store the information about whether this button is selected or not. Alternatively, you can use odd tags for buttons which are not selected and even tags for those which are selected. With this approach you can still easily obtain the index of clicked button ;)